# SQL - how to merge the 2 queries together to obtain my desired result

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables 'Climber' & 'YearResults' 
[image]
[image]

My desired result is to show sum(moneyWon), order by 'nationality'.

I've done the query to join the two tables & sum the moneyWon but how should I join these 2 queries that it will show total sum of money won by each nationality.

```
select sum(moneyWon) from yearResults

(SELECT C.NATIONALITY, Y.MONEYWON, Y.YEAR
FROM CLIMBER c JOIN YEARRESULTS y
ON C.CLIMBERID = Y.CLIMBERID)
```

Comment: group by nationality

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to JOIN the tables and use grouping by nationality to get the results you need:

```
SELECT 
    Climber.Nationality, 
    SUM(yearResults.MoneyWon) as MoneyWon
FROM Climber 
    INNER JOIN yearResult ON Climber.ClimberID = yearResults.ClimberID
GROUP BY Climber.Nationality
ORDER BY Climber.Nationality
```